# Windows software RAID 1 with EFI bootloader on both disks

Tags: windows, software-raid, uefi

I have a Windows Server 2008r2 with two HDDs installed. The main partition, which has Windows installation on it, is mirrored between the two disks.

The problem is, this is a UEFI machine, and EFI partition is only on one of the HDDs. So if this HDD fails, the system won't boot from the second HDD until I reinstall bootloader on it (with Windows Recovery Console for example). Obviously, it greatly increases potential downtime in case of a disk failure.

Is there a way to install Windows EFI bootloaders on both disks, so if one of the disks fails, the second one will boot?

Comment: Yes, you can. You copy the bootloader across: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951985